# Syncing Folder Across Several PC

Tags: sync

A few friends and I are playing around with a modded Minecraft and since mods are constantly added and removed it becomes necessary to sync the mods and config folders several times. Ideally the synchronization would let the source/host upload to a cloud/internet service which would distribute to all clients so download times are kept low. But Host -> Clients would be fine, too. There are only 4-5 people who all trust each other so user/permission management is somewhat unnecessary.

he most important point is probably that it is configurable to only synchronize in one direction. I.E. changes on clients do not affect host. 
Even if there is nothing that fits those needs exactly, any suggestions that beat having to throw all the folders into a zip file and sharing it via dropbox is appreciated.

All systems involved are running on Windows 8.1 or 7.

Comment: Share a Dropbox account.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at SyncToy from Microsoft, it has, among others, one-directional sync for folders or for entire drives, has a GUI setup/user interface, and the command line version may also be scheduled via windows tasks to automate it.

Answer (score 1):

I currently do something similar to this with [BTsync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync).  It uses bit torrent protecall and will work accross a local LAN and or WAN.  You can setup multiple sync types as well.  As in all your friends can sync from your folder only, or all folders match each other... The best part is it does not limit file size and or folder size.  You can sync as much as you local hard drive has room.  It is instant (as in once a new file is added it starts to move it).  So you do not need to trigger/schedule a job to run once you add new files.